# C# Message box error that not allows to give title on message box

Tags: c#, windows

I want to give a title on the message box.

```
MessageBox.Show("UserName Or Password Does Not Match !!","Error Message");
```

I have used the above statement to give heading on the message box where the first is shown in the message box and second one is the title of message box.

```
MessageBox.Show("Are You Login As : "+ dt.Rows[i][1]);
```

in above statement i want to give message but can not working.

Comment: not working - could you elloborate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you confused between [string concatenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/concatenate-multiple-strings) and passing two parameters to Message.Show().

[Message.Show(string, string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_MessageBox_Show_System_String_System_String_), method of expect two strings,

1. The text to display in the message box.
2. The text to display in the title bar of the message box.

e.g.

```
MessageBox.Show("UserName Or Password Does Not Match !!","Error Message");
```

In your case, `MessageBox.Show("Are You Login As : "+ dt.Rows[i][1]);`, you are concatenating two string using `+` operator which only displays text in message body. `+ dt.Rows[i][1]` is not a second parameter passed to `Show()` method.

You need to pass second parameter with comma,

```
MessageBox.Show("Are You Login As : "+ dt.Rows[i][1], "Title");
```

To make it simpler, you can use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), like

```
MessageBox.Show($"Are You Login As : {dt.Rows[i][1]}", "Title");
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't write a title. If you want to write please add a string after comma

Yours:

```
 MessageBox.Show("Are You Login As : "+ dt.Rows[i][1]);
```

Mine:

```
MessageBox.Show("Are You Login As : "+ dt.Rows[i][1], "Title");
```

Comment: Thanks mark it as an answer so in future it will help others too.